# Incorrect reputation being displayed

Tags: support, bug, status-completed

> Please don't mistake me as *crazy*. I was just wondering if other users have seen about this case...

At the start (for a day), I had 2980 rep. I just returned now, answered a [question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/46927) here. The user up-voted me and chosen it as his answer. Then, I blinked at my user card showing 3005 rep. Then, something bugged the author (maybe a *formula*), he deselected mine and selected the other one. Then, I see my rep. still showing 2980 and not 2990 as my answer still has the vote.

**NOTE:** That 10 rep. is not a great deal though. But, I'm curious whether users have seen such a *thing* (bug) around in SE..?

Comment: Or the *other way round*, Is there any issue with my Firefox? **:-)**

Answer (score 2):

Try this: Go [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/reputation), scroll down, hit the "trigger rep recalc" button. That might fix it.

Also, check that you have the "show removed posts" box ticked at the bottom of https://physics.stackexchange.com/users/11062/crazy-buddy?tab=reputation

[image]

This will show posts which have been deleted as well (deleted posts you had downvoted on/your deleted posts that others had voted on). This may account for the discrepancy.

If both of these don't work, it's probably a bug

Answer (score 1):

This can happen, though rarely as a race condition in the accept and upvote saving to the database at the same time.  This is an artifact of your reputation update being `=` and not `+=`, and the base amount loaded in overlapping requests.  This can't really go away completely until we get rid of Linq2SQL completely and that's a huge task we have to stop and do.

In the mean time, this *does* get cleaned up at night since the new reputation history table, a log of every single event *doesn't* suffer from this symptom.  This allows us to do a summation and comparison every night, if there's a difference it'll fix your rep up, it's not perfect but it does ensure cases like this don't go ignored.