# How to recalc a Flair bug?

Tags: support, badges

This is also not a BIG issue (same as that of my previous question along with *disclaimer*...)

[Incorrect reputation being displayed](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2845) - where Manish explained me about *recalc'ing* rep. But, there is some *mysterious* problem regarding **[my flairs](https://physics.stackexchange.com/users/11062/crazy-buddy/flair)** now..!

My dark theme shows 49 badges while my other themes show 50. I know that my flair updates every now & then. But, what calc made it go mad?

[image: Flair]

Answer (score 1):

This time it's caching on your side. Your computer has saved a copy of the image locally so it doesn't have to download it again and again, it may download it only once a day or so.

On my side I see:

[image]

So, most others can see 50 in your badge count, and it'll probably update for you sooner or later.

Comment: caching.. caching... caching... Whaaaa..?
Is it happening only to the dark theme then?

Comment: @CrazyBuddy: That's because your profile contains the dark theme and you view it often.

Comment: A simple change in "1 badge" caused this much problem then..?

Comment: @CrazyBuddy: It's not a problem in my eyes. You view your profile often. Your profile contains the dark theme. Your browser, to save bandwidth, keeps a copy of the dark flair locally. It doesn't do that for the others, since you rarely see those. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Temporary_Internet_Files

Comment: Again, the problem is only visible to you. And it'll smoothen out in a day or so.

Comment: Ok, I understood it already. Just curious and wondered "How that single badge caused this?" Maybe, I'll have to clear out the cache..!

Comment: @CrazyBuddy http://stackoverflow.com/a/385384/1134387

Comment: @Bernhard: Thank you very much Berhard. But sadly, It didn't work. BTW, I've already cleared the cache folder manually. No use except I've to log into all my accounts again... Anyways - That shortcut - I didn't know.  :-)

Comment: @CrazyBuddy Your login info is not stored in the cache, but in cookies afaik. I think you cleared to much :)

Comment: @Bernhard: Hi Bernhard. I know that already. Now, I must explain clearly. I've cleared those login credentials from my browser already. Along with that, I deleted the cache and then I restarted my browser. All these happened once I got the answer from Manish. :-)

Answer (score 1):

We cache these at a few levels in some cases for up to 3 days, this is normal and expected.  We may optimize how flair works a bit later as some of the avatar discussions progress internally, we'll update meta.so with that if it any changes are made to improve user flair overall.

Comment: Thanks for your reply Nick. Though it is not so important, I just thought it was some *bug* :-)